# Move div 100% to the left off the visible screen and scroll to

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want to move a div so far to the left that it kind of mirrors a "second" screen you need to scroll to. There is absolutely no reason one would like to do this, I am just trying to learn something.

So it looks more or less like this. When I set `right: 100%`it does not work!

```css
.outer-container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 66vw;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <h1>I'm very on the left</h1>
</div>
```

When I change `right: 100%;` to `left: 100%` it does work! What am I doing wrong here?

```css
.outer-container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 66vw;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <h1>I'm very on the right</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Overflow is hidden by default to the "start" side (which depends on language direction). You'll need a different solution.

Comment: thanks, did not know that!:) Any idea on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're confused with how to use `position: absolute`. While using absolute, `right: 100%` or `left: %100` is going to kick it in the opposite direction. Moreover, your css states to move it 100% and it's moving it right off the screen since your width is set to `width: 66vw`. So, `right: 0 or left: 0` would be what you're looking for.

Just to drive it home, if you put `top: 20%` it will move the div 20% away from the top. Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-kate-n0v06?file=/index.html).